# What does console.log use to convert this to string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, console.log

What does `console.log` use to convert a variable into a string?

```
 console.log('DEBUGGING', this, JSON.stringify(this), String(this), this.toString(), `${this}`);
```

I'm logging the above and receiving:

```
DEBUGGING restaurant undefined class extends Model {} class extends Model {} class extends Model
```

I need the `restaurant` string saved to a variable, however only `console.log` logs this - every other method of converting to a string produces `class extends Model {}` which is useless to me.

Comment: Please make your runtime more clear. Node.js uses `util.inspect()`, but I am not sure about web browsers.

Comment: I'm running this in node.

Comment: @0xLogN `util.inspect()` works! If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'm happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, I was told this was Node. OP, please include that in your question in the future!

If I was to write my own implementation of console.log, it would probably look similar to the following:

```js
const util = require('util');
console.log = function log(...params) {
    process.stdout.write(params.map(v => typeof v === 'string' ? v : util.inspect(v)) + '\n');
}
```

Notice [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-showhidden-depth-colors)? That's the magic. You can read up on it by clicking the link [to the docs (same link as earlier)](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-showhidden-depth-colors).