# Google Document AI - Inconsistent Long Running Operation's metadata JSON representation

Tags: node.js, long-running-processes, cloud-document-ai

While checking the status of Document AI - Long Running Operation (Form processor), the JSON representation of `decodedOperation.metadata` seems to vary during the execution.
I suspect that `operation` response does not resolve straight away despite using `then()`  on `checkBatchProcessDocumentsProgress(operation.name)`.

This behaviour **does not happen** using similar code for Google Speech's LROs.

### Context:

At `console.log` line #24 of implemented code (below), *as expected*, `decodedOperation.metadata` resolves to

```
{
   "state":"RUNNING",
   "createTime":{
      "seconds":"1669278029",
      "nanos":500249000
   },
   "updateTime":{
      "seconds":"1669278029",
      "nanos":500249000
   }
}
```

### Current behaviour:

At `console.log` line #27, `decodedOperation.metadata.state` returns `2` (!?)

### Expected behaviour:

`decodedOperation.metadata.state` should return `RUNNING`.

More details of output in the code below.

### Reproduction details:

**Environment:**
`node.js 12.02`

**Package.json:**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/documentai": "latest",
    }
}
```

**Code:**

```
function run() {

    const documentai = require('@google-cloud/documentai').v1;

    // Create a promise on object
    let options = {
        credentials: {
            client_email: ** ** ** ,
            private_key: ** ** * ,
        },
        projectId: ** ** *
    };

    return async (async callback => {

        const client = new documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(options);
        client.checkBatchProcessDocumentsProgress(properties.operation)
            .then(
                (decodedOperation) => {

                    console.log("METADATA " + JSON.stringify(decodedOperation.metadata));
                    /* logs to console:  
                        {
                           "state":"RUNNING",
                           "createTime":{
                              "seconds":"1669278029",
                              "nanos":500249000
                           },
                           "updateTime":{
                              "seconds":"1669278029",
                              "nanos":500249000
                           }
                        }
                    /// then 
                        {
                         "state":"SUCCEEDED",
                         "createTime":{
                            "seconds":"1669278029",
                            "nanos":500249000
                         },
                         "updateTime":{
                            "seconds":"1669278048",
                            "nanos":758825000
                         },
                         "individualProcessStatuses":[
                            {
                               "inputGcsSource":"gs://bucket/intake-form.pdf",
                               "status":{

                               },
                               "outputGcsDestination":"gs://bucket/ocr/7371120297544371692/0",
                               "humanReviewStatus":{
                                  "state":"SKIPPED",
                                  "stateMessage":"HumanReviewConfig is DISABLED, skipping human review."
                               }
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                      */
                    console.log("STATE " + JSON.stringify(decodedOperation.metadata.state));
                    /* log to console: 2 
                     when above is "RUNNING" */

                    /* log to console: 3
                    when above is "SUCCEEDED" */

                    if (decodedOperation.metadata.state == "SUCCEEDED") { // Never triggers as decodedOperation.metadata.state evaluates to an integer at this line

                    };
                    let response = {
                        "operationStatus": decodedOperation.metadata.state
                    };
                    callback(undefined, response);
                })
            .catch(
                (err) => {
                    callback(err);
                });
    })
}
```

### Update on investigation

`util.inspect(decodedOperation.metadata, { showHidden: false })` returns:

```
BatchProcessMetadata {
   {
      "individualProcessStatuses":[
         "IndividualProcessStatus"{
            "inputGcsSource":"gs://bucketxxx/intake-form.pdf",
            "status":[
               "Status"
            ],
            "outputGcsDestination":"gs://bucketxxx/ocr/7999521463088838887/0",
            "humanReviewStatus":[
               "HumanReviewStatus"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "state":3,
      "createTime":"Timestamp"{
         "seconds":"Long"{
            "low":1670011754,
            "high":0,
            "unsigned":false
         },
         "nanos":105214000
      },
      "updateTime":"Timestamp"{
         "seconds":"Long"{
            "low":1670011773,
            "high":0,
            "unsigned":false
         },
         "nanos":489028000
      }
   }
```

`util.inspect(decodedOperation.metadata, { showHidden: true })` returns (section of interest only):

`[...] [root]: [Getter], [fullName]: [Getter] }, State: { STATE_UNSPECIFIED: 0, WAITING: 1, RUNNING: 2, SUCCEEDED: 3, CANCELLING: 4, CANCELLED: 5, FAILED: 6, '0': 'STATE_UNSPECIFIED', '1': 'WAITING', '2': 'RUNNING', '3': 'SUCCEEDED', '4': 'CANCELLING', '5': 'CANCELLED', '6': 'FAILED' }, encode: <ref *5> [Function: BatchProcessMetadata$encode] [...]`

Comment: Hi @redvivi, can you confirm whether `decodedOperation.metadata.state` is always returning 2 or any other value since you mentioned that you are getting different results?

Comment: Hi @Shipra.Sarkar. Oddly enough, it looks like integer 2 is returned when state is “RUNNING” and 3 when state is “SUCCEEDED”.

Comment: Hi @redvivi, can you try by using this `console.log("STATE " + decodedOperation.metadata.state);` ? Let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Hi @Shipra.Sarkar. No change. It still returns an integer. Besides, `if (decodedOperation.metadata.state == <integer>)` returns true if implemented.

Comment: Hi @Shipra.Sarkar, please advise.

Comment: Hi @redvivi, Can you try the solution provided in this [Stackoverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251166/what-does-console-log-use-to-convert-this-to-string)?

Comment: @Shipra.Sarkar: Unfortunately, same results.

Comment: @Shipra.Sarkar added results of util() analysis, I think it is getting clearer that the object returns is not a pure JSON.

Comment: Hi @redvivi, is your issue resolved?

Comment: No @Shipra.Sarkar, see my latest update for new findings. Requesting your guidance.

Comment: No answer from Google @Shipra.Sarkar?